# Missed opportunity to fix JDBC date handling in Java 8?

Tags: java, date, jdbc, java-8

Can any Java 8 + JDBC expert tell me if something's wrong in the following reasoning? And, if in the secrets of Gods, why this hasn't been done?

A `java.sql.Date` is currently the type used by JDBC to map to the DATE SQL type, which represents a date without time, and without timezone. But this class is awfully designed, since it's in fact a subclass of `java.util.Date`, which stores a precise instant in time, up to the millisecond.

To represent the date 2015-09-13 in database, we're thus forced to choose a timezone, parse the string "2015-09-13T00:00:00.000" in that timezone as a java.util.Date to get a millisecond value, then construct a `java.sql.Date` from this millisecond value, and finally call `setDate()` on the prepared statement, passing a Calendar holding the timezone chosen in order for the JDBC driver to be able to correctly recompute the date 2015-09-13 from this millisecond value. This process is made a bit simpler by using the default timezone everywhere, and not passing a Calendar.

Java 8 introduces a LocalDate class, which is a much better fit for the DATE database type, since it's not a precise moment in time, and is thus not dependent on the timezone. And Java 8 also introduces default methods, which would allow to make backward-compatible changes to the PreparedStatement and ResultSet interfaces.

So, haven't we missed a huge opportunity to clean up the mess in JDBC while still maintaining backward compatibility? Java 8 could simply have added those default methods to PreparedStatement and ResultSet:

```
default public void setLocalDate(int parameterIndex, LocalDate localDate) {
    if (localDate == null) {
        setDate(parameterIndex, null);
    }
    else {
        ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(utc).toInstant());
        Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
        setDate(parameterIndex, sqlDate, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(utc)));
    }
}

default LocalDate getLocalDate(int parameterIndex) {
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    Date sqlDate = getDate(parameterIndex, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(utc)));
    if (sqlDate == null) {
        return null;
    }

    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
    return utilDate.toInstant().atZone(utc).toLocalDate();
}
```

Of course, the same reasoning applies to the support of Instant for the TIMESTAMP type, and the support of LocalTime for the TIME type.

Comment: Instead of doing that, they are simply telling you to use the `setObject` method. If the object happens to be a `LocalDate`, up-to-date JDBC drivers are supposed to know what to do with it.

Comment: I've seen that. But it's a pity, because we have to wait for up-to-date drivers, and libraries can never be sure the JDBC driver will indeed support LocalDate, so they reimplement this functionality instead of relying on a default implementation. And we still have to do getDate().toLocalDate() on a ResultSet to get a LocalDate.

Comment: Or use a `getObject(int,Class)` and rely on the JDBC driver to be able to handle it. Anyway, that's their policy for now. Question is, what kind of answers do you expect to get from SO on this issue?

Comment: The one I got is OK, and I'll accept it. Basically, I read it as "yes, I agree, but there is a workaround". I would also have accepted "your reasoning is completely flawed, and here's why" :-)

Comment: @JBNizet this is a big can of worms, we have decided on one big project to represent date without time and without timezone as a String instead...

Comment: Here is some insight into the decision making: [Overview on OpenJdK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2012-December/000010.html).

Comment: That's ridiculous but it's the 10th of January, 2017 now and Oracle still don't provide JDBC 4.2 driver, what a shame!  Microsoft presented it's JDBC 4.2-compatible driver in the September of 2015!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> To represent the date 2015-09-13 in database, we're thus forced to choose a timezone, parse the string "2015-09-13T00:00:00.000" in that timezone as a java.util.Date to get a millisecond value, then construct a java.sql.Date from this millisecond value, and finally call setDate() on the prepared statement, passing a Calendar holding the timezone chosen in order for the JDBC driver to be able to correctly recompute the date 2015-09-13 from this millisecond value

Why? Just call

```
Date.valueOf("2015-09-13"); // From String
Date.valueOf(localDate);    // From java.time.LocalDate
```

The behaviour will be the correct one in all JDBC drivers: The local date without timezone. The inverse operation is:

```
date.toString();    // To String
date.toLocalDate(); // To java.time.LocalDate
```

You should never rely on [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)'s dependency on [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and the fact that it thus inherits the semantics of a [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) via [`Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-long-) or [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--)

> So, haven't we missed a huge opportunity to clean up the mess in JDBC while still maintaining backward compatibility? [...]

It depends. The [JDBC 4.2 spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html) specifies that you are able to bind a `LocalDate` type via [`setObject(int, localDate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-), and to fetch a `LocalDate` type via [`getObject(int, LocalDate.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-), if the driver is ready for that. Not as elegant as more formal `default` methods, as you suggested, of course.

Comment: I missed the valueOf(LocalDate) method (I was looking for a from() method like `java.util.Date.from(Instant)`), and forgot about the valueOf(String) method. It's still is mess, since we have to know which timezone was used when constructing the Date to call the correct setDate() method. I'm not sure how I can avoid relying on the fact that it uses milliseconds, since the only non-deprecated constructor it has takes milliseconds as argument.

Comment: Regarding the last part, I find it ugly: we have to wait for Java8-compliant drivers, and it's far from obvious that setObject()/getObject() must be used instead of the usual setXxx()/getXxx() methods existing for all the other types. LocalDate isn't even mentioned in the javadoc.

Comment: It is an ugly mess, yes. With `java.sql.Date`, things get a bit simpler when you just look at it as a container of the string version of the date. However, try not to send a serialized instance of `java.sql.Date` to a client on another timezone.

Comment: "The behaviour will be the correct one in all JDBC drivers: The local date without timezone." I didn't get that part. Because `java.sql.Date` does track timezone inherently, _some_ time zone has to be assumed. Does `Date.valueOf(localDate)` and `Date.toLocalDate()` automatically convert to/from UTC? Unfortunately from a bit of research I suspect it uses the default (system) time zone, which would mean we still have to do time zone gymnastics to normalize to/from UTC, don't we?

Comment: @GarretWilson *"Because java.sql.Date does track timezone inherently"* - If used properly, it doesn't do that. But yes, it's easy to mis-use this type due to its extending `java.util.Date`, e.g. by calling its `Date(long)` constructor, which makes no sense at all, and which unfortunately isn't deprecated. / *"Does Date.valueOf(localDate) and Date.toLocalDate() automatically convert to/from UTC? "* Why should UTC play a role? The type is a local date. It has no notion of time zones.

Comment: Because `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`, I assumed it keeps track of the "date" by using a certain number of milliseconds since the epoch in UTC, with the time zeroed out. That's how `java.util.Date` works, which means it must be how `java.sql.Date`, which extends it, works. So to go round-trip `LocalDate`->`java.sql.Date`->SQL DATE->`java.sql.Date`->`LocalDate`, you have to use the same time zone conversion to/from `Date` in order to have the number of millisecond wind up the same, right? Does `Date.valueOf(localDate)` guarantee it uses UTC to determine milliseconds for `Date`?

Comment: ...and in fact, if you follow the source code, you'll see that `java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate date)` extracts the year, month, and day from the `LocalDate` (good) but then eventually calls the `java.util.Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec)` constructor, which assumes the values are "in the local time zone" :( So... it seems to me that `java.sql.Date` is indeed inherently tracking the time zone, the conversion from `LocalDate` will be in the local time zone, and if you turn around and load it from the DB on another system you could get a different `LocalDate`.

Comment: I guess one other question is whether JDBC guarantees that extracting the SQL DATE from a `java.sql.Date` will also use the local time zone; if JDBC guarantees this, and you don't change the time zone in the middle, you may get lucky and `LocalDate`->`java.sql.Date`->SQL Date will store the correct `YYYY-MM-DD`. But if you were to switch time system time zone after converting to `java.sql.Date` before storing in the database (and that actually could happen) you'd still be be screwed. It seems brittle without normalizing to UTC.

Comment: @GarretWilson: Well, the Lishkov substitution principle was violated many times in early JDK libraries... The JDBC spec clearly indicates what a `java.sql.Date` is. It just doesn't match the expectation given the inheritance.

Comment: I think the Lishkov Substitution Principle is missing the point. Whatever the JDBC spec indicates that `java.sql.Date` _means_, its _internal implementation_ has certain real-life implications. If you don't normalize to UTC, there are two scenarios in which you could read different values than what you wrote. Do you understand what I'm saying? I suppose I'll need to create a unit tests to show this more clearly. Maybe I'm completely off track here, but I'm not sure everyone is understanding my point.

Comment: @GarretWilson: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: no, date time handling is fixed in Java 8 / JDBC 4.2 because it has support for [Java 8 Date and Time types](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html). This can not be emulated using default methods.

> Java 8 could simply have added those default methods to PreparedStatement and ResultSet:

This is not possible for several reasons:

- `java.time.OffsetDateTime` has not equivalent in `java.sql`
- `java.time.LocalDateTime` breaks on DST transitions when converting through `java.sql.Timestamp` because the latter depends on the JVM time zone, see code below
- `java.sql.Time` has millisecond resolution but `java.time.LocalTime` has nanosecond resolution

Therefore you need proper driver support, default methods would have to convert through `java.sql` types which introduces data loss.

If you run this code in a JVM time zone with daylight savings time it will break. It searches the next transition in which the clocks are "set forward" and picks a `LocalDateTime` that is right in the middle of the transition. This is perfectly valid because Java `LocalDateTime` or SQL `TIMESTAMP` have no time zone and therefore no time zone rules and therefore no daylight saving time. `java.sql.Timestamp` on the other hand is bound to the JVM time zone and therefore subject to daylight saving time.

```
ZoneId systemTimezone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
Instant now = Instant.now();

ZoneRules rules = systemTimezone.getRules();
ZoneOffsetTransition transition = rules.nextTransition(now);
assertNotNull(transition);
if (!transition.getDateTimeBefore().isBefore(transition.getDateTimeAfter())) {
  transition = rules.nextTransition(transition.getInstant().plusSeconds(1L));
  assertNotNull(transition);
}

Duration gap = Duration.between(transition.getDateTimeBefore(), transition.getDateTimeAfter());
LocalDateTime betweenTransitions = transition.getDateTimeBefore().plus(gap.dividedBy(2L));

Timestamp timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(betweenTransitions);
assertEquals(betweenTransitions, timestamp.toLocalDateTime());
```