# Is MariaDB Java Client 1.5.7 compliant with JDBC 4.2

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I'm using `LocalDate` in Java 8 and I'm trying to `INSERT` data into a table in MariaDB. I'm using MariaDB Java Client 1.5.7. I get an error message that I can't insert a `LocalDate` when I try to `INSERT` the data. Reading some posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238011/2420986) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085461/2420986) this shouldn't be an issue for drivers that support JDBC 4.2. Does MariaDB Java Client 1.5.7 client support JDBC 4.2? The error message sort of tells me that it is not working but I just want to make that I don't have some errors in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - no, it doesn't.
By checking out their [about page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/) you can see that the 1.5.x generation of MariaDB JDBC drivers support JDK 7, which includes JDBC 4.1, not 4.2

Comment: I gave 2.0.2 a try and it didn't work either. I guess it is not supported yet.