# Fetching date from JSpinner and putting in MySQL database column having DATE format

Tags: java, mysql, swing, simpledateformat, jspinner

I'm developing a java program and I wish to input date from user.

For this I have used a JSpinner and set it's model type as **Date** from Spinner Model Editor.
Also, by default the spinner also displays **time** with its and I don't want time, but only date thus, I created a new *SimpleDateFormat* and applied to spinner.
Here's the code for SimpleDateFormat :-

```
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
dateSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(dateSpinner,date_format.toPattern()));
```

I used DateFormat becuase I want to display the date in ***dd-mm-yyyy*** format.

After that I used **stateChanged Method** to fetch the date selected by user via JSpinner.
The body of method is as follows :-

```
private void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {        

    Date dateChosen = (Date) dateSpinner.getValue();

    int date = dateChosen.getDate();
    int month = ( dateChosen.getMonth() ) + 1;
    int year = ( dateChosen.getYear() ) + 1900;        
    String DB_Date = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(date);

   // 1 was added to **month** because month's were 1 less than the conventional human format
   // also, 1900 was added to **year** to make it suitable for apperance of human conventions

}
```

Now, I wish to input this date from user to my MySQL database column whose data type is **DATE**.
For this, i tried the following :-
 1. I tried to use the **setDate( )** method with its parameter as *dateChosen*, whose code is as follows :-

```
PreparedStatement stmt = new PreparedStatement();
stmt.setDate (column_no, (java.sql.Date) dateChosen);
```

But instead the date was not stored and the date column of MySQL table was left blank.
.
2. I tried to use the **setString( )** method with its parameter as *DB_Date*, whose code is as follow :-

```
 PreparedStatement stmt = new PreparedStatemnt();
 stmt.setString (column_no, DB_Date);
```

But, again the (date) column of MySQL table was left blank.

Now, I want to know how can I store the date from JSpinner to my MySQL table column whose data type is **DATE**.
Also, if the there is any other approach than using JSpinner to store the date in MySQL table then please tell me that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` type in `JDBC` is `java.sql.Date` and in other case is `java.util.Date`,they are not the same and can not be convert directly

You can try with below code

```
PreparedStatement stmt = new PreparedStatement();
stmt.setDate (column_no, new java.sql.Date(dateChosen.getTime()));
```

BTW,if you are using `java-8` and `jdbc-4` ,the more suitable way is to use **[LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)**

```
stmt.setDate (column_no, localDate.now());
```

Comment: Thanks, the first approach did work for me.

On trying the second approach I get error "Incompatible types : LocalDate cannot be converted to Date"

Comment: @AlphaSniper for the second,you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548331/missed-opportunity-to-fix-jdbc-date-handling-in-java-8

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

Assuming you can use at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2:

```
    LocalDate dateToSave = dateChosen.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
    stmt.setObject(column_no, dateToSave);
```

Don’t save the date as a string to MySQL. Use a date object. And certainly prefer the modern `LocalDate` over the long outdated `java.sql.Date` with the problematic design. Note the use of `setObject()` rather than `setDate()`.

Here we cannot completely avoid the old-fashioned `java.util.Date` class since the spinner is giving us one (you may want to research whether you can fill `LocalDate` objects into the spinner instead, but it’s not my home field, I cannot tell). In this case the first thing to do is to convert the `Date` to the modern `Instant` class so we can do the rest of our work using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

I believe you *can* avoid the old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` class, though. Just do the simpler:

```
    dateSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(dateSpinner, "dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Finally, since `PreparedStatement` is an interface, not a class, you cannot do what you tried:

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = new PreparedStatemnt(); // Nogo; cannot instantiate the type PreparedStatement
```

It’s outside this question, so I’ll just mention that you need a `Connection`. I trust that you will find out (and if not, ask a new question).