# JdbcTemplate INSERT query issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, derby, jdbctemplate

I have built a DAO for my INSERT query. Code:

**DAO**

```
public class EmployeeDao {
    JdbcTemplate template;  
    public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;  
    }  
    public int insert(EmployeeInfo emp){

        String sql = "insert into employee VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        int i=template.update(sql, emp.getFirstName(), emp.getMiddleName(), emp.getLastName(), emp.getEmail(), emp.getGender(), emp.getDob(), emp.getAddress1(), emp.getAddress2(), emp.getEmpID());

        return i;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Autowired  
EmployeeDao dao;
@RequestMapping("/addresult")  
public ModelAndView addResult(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {

    String fname = req.getParameter("FirstName");
    String mname = req.getParameter("MiddleName");
    String middlename;
    if(mname!="null"&&mname.trim()!=""){
        middlename=mname;
    }
    else
    {
        middlename="-";
    }
    String lname = req.getParameter("LastName");
    //int empID = Integer.getInteger(req.getParameter("empID")).intValue();
    String empid = req.getParameter("empID");
    int empID = Integer.parseInt(empid);
    String email = req.getParameter("Email");
    String gender = req.getParameter("gender");
    //Date dob = Date.valueOf(req.getParameter("DOB"));
    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(req.getParameter("DOB")); 
    String addr1 = req.getParameter("address1");
    String addr2 = req.getParameter("address2");
    EmployeeInfo emp = new EmployeeInfo(fname,middlename,lname,email,gender,dob,addr1,addr2,empID);

    int ret = dao.insert(emp);

    if(ret==0){
        return new ModelAndView("EmployeeAddResult","mess","Success");
    }
    else
    {
    return new ModelAndView("EmployeeAddResult","mess","hi");
    }
}
```

When I run my webapp, the INSERT query results in an error:

[image]

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert
>   into employee VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [XJ021];
>   error code [20000]; Type is not supported.; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Type is not supported.

What's the reason behind this issue?

Comment: What is the type returned by `getDob` ? Most likely one of `java.time` API that is not supported by the JPA used here. EDIT : How, well this is a `LocalDate` as I though.

Comment: @AxelH is it a joda time issue??

Comment: Joda ? Please show the import line where you have `LocalDate` imported. And the short answer, no. This is a problem of type support from Spring.

Comment: i have imported joda time in my controller file

Comment: Convert the `dob` to a regular `date` before inserting. `emp.getDob().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `java.sql.Date` instead of `LocalDate`, add the following date instead:

```
Date date = Date.valueOf(dob);
```

Comment: @SiddhantSahni for using `LocalDate` see Demo https://gist.github.com/jmarton/5320cbcfa8a382c83ae2ae28d77d4237 if it's not working it can be a driver issue see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548331/missed-opportunity-to-fix-jdbc-date-handling-in-java-8

Comment: Okay, I'll look into the it. Thanks.